# laptop has internal modem, but network connections only shows ethernet and wifi

Tags: modem

How do I get the internal modem (model/make unknown) of my Panasonic CF-73 Toughbook with Ubuntu 17.04 on it, to be an option in the network selections? 
How do I get my browser to use it for dial-up (how do I get the modem on the options menu)?

ie on the network connection drop down menu of THIS computer the only options are 'ethernet' and 'wifi', there is no 'modem' or 'dial-up' option as I've seen pictures posted of [like those here, for example](https://www.debianadmin.com/images/dailup/1.png)

I installed modem manager, which did not seem to see the internal modem (possibly winmodem or software modem) - SO, I plugged in my PCMCIA US Robotics modem into the PCMCIA slot (please don't ask me to plug it into a usb connection...) and modem manager indicates:

"Modem is not ready for operation. Please wait while modem being prepared" is noted next to the blue "i", and below the message is 'select device':

(null)(null)
Version:(null) Port:ttyS2 Type:GSM

but still no 'modem' in network options...

here's this with the internal (present?) and pcmcia modem plugged into pcmcia slot per request (forget usb please):

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Modem
00:1e.3 Modem [0703]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Modem Controller [8086:266d] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Matsushita Electric Industrial Co., Ltd. 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Modem Controller [10f7:834b]
    Kernel modules: snd_intel8x0m
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801FBM (ICH6M) LPC Interface Bridge [8086:2641] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Matsushita Electric Industrial Co., Ltd. 82801FBM (ICH6M) LPC Interface Bridge [10f7:8338]
```

Do notice that when pcmcia modem is plugged in, 'enable mobile broadband' is added to the network dropdown menu, but the modem is 56k... and while enable mobile broadband is 'checked', it indicates above it that mobile broadband is 'not enabled'.

NEW - Got friend from Israel to get the modem working using GNOME-PPP.
However, it seems though that when it gets to the username and password part it fails to login. Putting the pcmcia modem back into my win98 laptop, and trying the same username, password, phone number, then it works fine, but back into the ubuntu laptop and this:

```
$ sudo gnome-ppp
[sudo] password for cf73: 
WVCONF: /home/cf73/.wvdial.conf
GNOME PPP: Connecting...
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Initializing modem.
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Sending: ATZ
GNOME PPP: STDERR: ATZ
GNOME PPP: STDERR: OK
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
GNOME PPP: STDERR: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
GNOME PPP: STDERR: OK
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Modem initialized.
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Sending: ATM1L3DT404,2483900
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Waiting for carrier.
GNOME PPP: STDERR: ATM1L3DT404,2483900
GNOME PPP: STDERR: CONNECT 33333/ARQ/x2/LAPM/V42BIS
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Carrier detected.  Waiting for prompt.
GNOME PPP: STDERR: STATION ID - nrcga11rh03hp013,nrcga41ev
GNOME PPP: STDERR: Welcome 
GNOME PPP: STDERR: Please Sign-on: 
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Looks like a login prompt.
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Sending: jaim (edited)
GNOME PPP: STDERR: jaim (edited)
GNOME PPP: STDERR: Name, password pair incorrect
GNOME PPP: STDERR: Please Sign-on: 
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Looks like a login prompt.
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Sending: jaim (edited)
GNOME PPP: STDERR: jaim (edited)
GNOME PPP: STDERR: Name, password pair incorrect
GNOME PPP: STDERR: Please Sign-on: 
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Looks like a login prompt.
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Sending: jaim (edited)
GNOME PPP: STDERR: jaim (edited)
GNOME PPP: STDERR: Name, password pair incorrect
GNOME PPP: STDERR: Please Sign-on: 
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Looks like a login prompt.
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Sending: jaim (edited)
GNOME PPP: STDERR: jaim (edited)
GNOME PPP: STDERR: Login failed, reason = (-190,nrcga41ev,1501768937-000,nrcga11rh03hp013)
GNOME PPP: STDERR: Connection closed by foreign host.
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Connected, but carrier signal lost!  Retrying...
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Sending: ATM1L3DT404,2483900
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Waiting for carrier.
GNOME PPP: STDERR: N
GNOME PPP: STDERR: O
GNOME PPP: STDERR: ATM1L3DT404,2483900
GNOME PPP: STDERR:  CARRIER
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Carrier detected.  Waiting for prompt.
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Connected, but carrier signal lost!  Retrying...
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Sending: ATM1L3DT404,2483900
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Waiting for carrier.
GNOME PPP: STDERR: ATM1L3DT404,2483900
GNOME PPP: STDERR: Caught signal 2:  Attempting to exit gracefully...
GNOME PPP: STDERR: --> Disconnecting at Thu Aug  3 10:02:39 2017
```

Comment: How is the modem connected to the laptop? If it's internal or plugged into a side slot, could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Modem`? If it's connected via USB, include the output of `lsusb` instead. Thanks.

Comment: When the modem is connected and as you say ¨ 'enable mobile broadband' is added", that means the modem has been correctly detected as such. Now you need to enable and configure according to the ISP instructions. Do you still have analogue dial-up service in your area? Well, it seems so, "lucky" you, in Europe we no longer have that... Now, assuming you're successful in setting up and connecting, what exactly do you intend to do with 56k? No modern website will load...

Comment: "Now you need to enable and configure according to the ISP instructions"
...if only I knew how to enable and then get it configured! 
But, yes - dial up via cordless phone line has always been an option when wifi is unavailable as I live in a motorhome and 'wires' are 'out'. Mainly use for email and websites such as this that aren't so 'dynamic' that the constant reloading of content stalls it loading fully (modern indeed - more like monster websites...). I don't do streaming, youtube, etc. so email access, search engine use, etc are my mainstays, not the 'eyecandy' stuff...

Comment: Seems problem with gnome-ppp was it needed the settings to use something called "stupid mode" - immediately went online w/no problem... slower than uverse broadband, but a good backup ;-)
Thanks to Jacques!

Comment: However, once I changed my online ISP password, then changed it in gnome-ppp, it 'broke' and is back to logon username/password problem and no online access via dialup again - sheesh, this linux stuff breaks so easily. Apparently wvdial and gnome-ppp are very unstable software but that's all that is available for dialup....what a lost cause!